# Insert to join table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `member_registry` which holds the member information and its columns contain of:

`-id`
`-member_name`
`-member_email`
`-member_password`
`-member_phone`

---

And I have a table named `estock` which function to get the posted data of the product they want to buy. Its columns contain of:

`-member_id`
`-product_name`
`-product_quantity`
`-product_price`

---

And then I have a table named `products` which its columns contain of:

`-product_id`
`-product_name`
`-product_price`
`-product_image`

---

What I want is when the user submit the product they want to buy to the table of `estock`

I want to be able to get their name (member_registry.member_name) that will be posted to the `estock` table in the column estock.member_id.

One thing I've got to remember is that the username (member_registry.member_name) can be gotten from the session_username on the page.

---

And vice versa, after inserting the form data to the estock table,

I want to be able to get the data from the `estock` that will also containt information from `member_registry` table: `

Please, help me. this is my first time in joining table. I hope anyone understand what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

@klaudia  i think this will help you

```
SELECT * FROM member_registry
INNER JOIN estock ON member_registry.id = estock.member_id
WHERE your where statement
```

This will return eveything form both table based on your where statement.
if you want to get specific column then mention column name instead of * in SELECT statemet

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can execute both SELECT and INSERT at the same time? I'm no expert at SQL but i will probably do something like this:

```
$name = $_SESSION['session_username'];
$query = "SELECT id FROM member_registry WHERE member_name = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$memberRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$member_id = $memberRow['id'];

$query = "INSERT INTO estock (member_id, product_name, product_quantity, product_price)
         VALUES ('$member_id',[value], [value], [value])";
mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit:**

If you mean that you want to get information from both estock and member_registry table, you can try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM estock AS e, member_registry AS m WHERE e.member_id = m.id";
```